# Should I assign the result of calling my class' designated initializer to self?

Tags: objective-c, initialization, core-plot

I was reading through the source of core-plot and ran across this code in `CPTColor`:

```
-(id)initWithCGColor:(CGColorRef)newCGColor
{
    if ( (self = [super init]) ) {            
        CGColorRetain(newCGColor);
        cgColor = newCGColor;
    }
    return self;
}

-(id)initWithComponentRed:(CGFloat)red green:(CGFloat)green blue:(CGFloat)blue alpha:(CGFloat)alpha
{
    CGFloat colorComponents[4];
    colorComponents[0] = red;
    colorComponents[1] = green;
    colorComponents[2] = blue;
    colorComponents[3] = alpha;
    CGColorRef color = CGColorCreate([CPTColorSpace genericRGBSpace].cgColorSpace, colorComponents);
    [self initWithCGColor:color];
    CGColorRelease(color);
    return self;
}
```

If `[self initWithCGColor:color];` results in `initWithCGColor`'s superclass assigning a different value to self, will that new value be returned from `initWithComponentRed:green:blue:alpha:`?

In other words, is `self` in the two init methods the same variable two distinct variables?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This setup is potentially fragile, and Joe's suggestion, assigning `self` in `initWithComponentRed:...` before returning that value will fix it.

Every method gets an argument, `self`, that points to the instance it was called on. The argument acts just like any other variable; there's nothing special about it. That's why it's possible to assign `self`, and why it's necessary to have an explicit `return` in initializers.

When you send `[super init]`, you're using the superclass's version of the `init` method, but the current instance will still be passed as `self`. Since initializers in Objective-C are allowed to destroy the object they receive and create and return a new one,* there is a potential for `self = [super init]` in `initWithColor:` to not be the same object as that pointed to by `self` back in `initWithComponentRed:...`.

If that happens, since you don't reassign `self` to point to that new, correctly-initialized object, you'll be returning an *uninitialized* object from `initWithComponentRed:...`.

This is only a practical concern if your superclass could possibly do the substitution I described, but there's also no reason, AFAIK, to not do that reassignment.

---

*Collections do this, for example, because they don't know how big they need to be at `alloc` time; I believe `NSNumber` also does this because it has cached values for instances representing small integers.

Comment: That's what I thought but I wanted to confirm it. To make extra sure, I wrote a simple test program where the superclass releases `self` and returns nil if the alpha channel is 0. In that case the subclass' initializer returns an invalid reference instead of the correct value of `nil`.

Comment: You are correct. This fixed now. See http://code.google.com/p/core-plot/source/detail?r=082ab717a53aa158003b9d8cdd376faeef3fd9ce

Answer (score 2):

No if `self` were to change (ex. if you were to implementing a color cache) `initWithComponentRed:green:blue:alpha:` would return the wrong object unless the code was changed to:

```
    ...
    self = [self initWithCGColor:color];
    CGColorRelease(color);
    return self;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`self` always refers to the same object. <strike>It is not a "variable", but a language key word.</strike> If one initializer is called after the other, the object is simply altered.

NB: Otherwise, your pour class would have a "split personality" ;-).

Comment: This is not really correct. 'self' _is_ a variable; it is an implicit argument to every method. The current instance is passed in as the value, but it is possible to reassign your local 'self' pointer. This just won't affect what happens in other methods.